# Send JMS message to IBM-MQ with MQIIH header

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

Can someone help me to send a JMS message to IBM-MQ with IIH (MQIIH) headers?

I am using the Spring Boot application with **mq-jms-spring-boot-starter** version **2.4.5**.

When I send a message it always goes with the RFH2 header although it sets `StrucId` as `IIH` in the message header.

```java
public void send(Request mqRequest) throws JMSException {
    log.info("sending with message [{}] to queue [{}].", mqRequest.getMessage(), QUEUE_NAME);
    MQQueue destinationQueue = new MQQueue(QUEUE_NAME);
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destinationQueue, mqRequest.getMessage(), message -> {
        log.info("setting standard JMS headers before sending");
       message.setJMSCorrelationID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        message.setJMSDestination(new MQQueue(QUEUE_NAME));
        message.setJMSTimestamp(System.nanoTime());
        message.setJMSType("MQIIH");
        message.setStringProperty("Authenticator", "********");
        message.setStringProperty("Format", "********");
        message.setStringProperty("ReplyToFormat", "********");
        message.setIntProperty("CommitMode", '0');
        message.setStringProperty("LTermOverride", "********");
        message.setStringProperty("MFSMapName", "********");
        message.setIntProperty("SecurityScope", 'C');
        message.setStringProperty("StrucId", "IIH ");
        message.setIntProperty("StrucLength", 84);
        message.setIntProperty("Version", 1);
        return message;
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this in JMS, you have to use the Java API classes [MQIIH](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=java-mqiih), `MQHeaderList`, `MQMessage`, `MQQueue` and `MQQueueManager` to create and send such a message.

Comment: Thanks, @DanielSteinmann do you have a sample code that I can refer to?

Comment: I added an answer which only uses `MQIIH` MQ Java class but everything else stays on the JMS API. Does this work four you?

Comment: Yes @DanielSteinmann it works perfectly fine, Now I have one more question. How can we pass trancode in IMS messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this with pure JMS, you have to use the [MQIIH](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=java-mqiih) helper class:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import javax.jms.BytesMessage;
import com.ibm.mq.headers.MQIIH;
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsConstants;
...

public void send(Request mqRequest) throws JMSException {
    log.info("sending with message [{}] to queue [{}].", mqRequest.getMessage(), QUEUE_NAME);
    MQIIH mqiih = new MQIIH();
    mqiih.setAuthenticator("***");
    // set other MQIIH header values
    ByteArrayOutputStream mqiihBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    mqiih.write(new DataOutputStream(mqiihBytes));
    String destinationQueue = "queue:///" + QUEUE_NAME + "?targetClient=1";
    jmsTemplate.send(destinationQueue, (MessageCreator) session -> {
        BytesMessage message = session.createBytesMessage();
        message.setStringProperty(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_FORMAT, "MQIMS");
        message.writeBytes(mqiihBytes.toByteArray());
        message.writeBytes("This Is The Body".getBytes());
        return message;

    });
}
```

With the queue option `targetClient=1` the usual RFH2 header with JMS meta information gets stripped. The message will look like this:

```
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2022.
IBM MQ Queue Load/Unload Utility
* DMPMQMSG Version:9.3.1.0 Created:Wed Jan 11 08:41:37 2023
* Qmgr  = QM1
* Queue = Q1

A VER 2
A RPT 0
A MST 8
A EXP -1
A FDB 0
A ENC 273
A CCS 819
A FMT MQIMS   
A PRI 4
A PER 1
A MSI 414D5120514D312020202020202020204337BB6301ED0140
A COI 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
A BOC 0
A RTQ                                                 
A RTM QM1                                             
A USR mqm         
A ACC 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
A AIX 2020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020
A PAT 28
A PAN runner.RemoteTestRunner     
A PTD 20230111
A PTT 08413426
A AOX 20202020
A GRP 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
A MSQ 1
A OFF 0
A MSF 0
A ORL -1
T IIH 
X 00000001000000
T T
X 0000011100000000
T         
X 00000000
T                         ***     
X 00000000000000000000000000000000
T     This Is The Body

Read    - Files:   0  Messages:1  Bytes:100
Written - Files:   0  Messages:1  Bytes:100
```

Comment: Thanks, @Daniel for your help it helps me a lot to connect with MQ with the IIH header.  Do you know how can we pass trancode (the transaction code that specifies the mode of the
transaction) in IMS message?

Comment: Adding the `trancode` is actually another question, so it would be better if you ask another question. Anyway: Have you looked at [How the IMS bridge deals with messages](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=applications-how-ims-bridge-deals-messages) and the `MQFMT_IMS_VAR_STRING` in chapter [MQMD Format](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=mqmd-format-mqchar8)?

Comment: Looks like you just have to add `LLZZ<trancode><data>` (LL: 2-byte length field specifying the total length of the IMS variable string, ZZ: 2-byte field containing flags that are significant to IMS).